# Why do I need to delete resources when using copy-assign operator?

Tags: c++, delete-operator, copy-assignment

Code like this from one of my books for example:

```
class HasPtr {
public:
    HasPtr(const HasPtr& h): ps(new std::string(*h.ps)), i(h.i) { }
    HasPtr(const std::string &s = std::string()): ps(new std::string(s)), i(0) { }
    HasPtr& operator=(const HasPtr&);
    ~HasPtr() { delete ps; }
private:
    std::string *ps;
    int i;
};

HasPtr& HasPtr::operator=(const HasPtr &rhs){
    auto newp = new string(*rhs.ps); // copy the underlying string
    delete ps; // free the old memory
    ps = newp; // copy data from rhs into this object
    i = rhs.i;
    return *this; // return this object
}
```

Seems like the inside of the operator= could just be:

```
*ps = *rhs.ps
i = rhs.i
return *this;
```

With no need to delete the pointer first, seems redundant to do so. It did mention it is written in a way to leave the object in a suitable state should an exception occur but didn't divulge past that, but I don't see what exception could occur that even my alternative wouldn't handle. Why is there a need to delete the object first before assigning?

Comment: You need to observe the [rule of three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) (which is trivially observed by following the [rule of zero](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22806523/315052)). Also use [copy-and-swap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) if you implement your own assignment operator.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit C++ Primer 5th Edition, Chapter 13.2.1

Comment: If you jump to page 644, they provide a fixed version of their assignment operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks fine to me.

And you're right, `std::string` assignment [already](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%3D) offers a strong exception guarantee so you will still leave the object in its original state should an exception occur copying the string.

Of course there is no reason to allocate a `std::string` with `new` like that. You could just write this instead:

```
class HasNoPtr {
public:
    HasNoPtr(const std::string& s): ps(s), i(0) { }
private:
    std::string ps;
    int i;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

In this case, yes, that would be fine.

You're not leaking the dynamically-allocated string: you're re-using it.